# ESLint/vs-code change path for tsconfig.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I have a directory with a folder for the frontend and a folder for the backend.

If I open vs-code to the frontend folder, linting works properly, but if I open vs-code to the parent folder, then the linter cannot get the correct path for tsconfig.json, and so the linting doesn't work.

ESlint expects tsconfig.json here:
`'/home/trones/Documents/git_repos/practice-and-examples/Angular/rxjs/convert to real api calls/tsconfig.json'`

but there's nothing here, this file does not exist.... tsconfig.json is in the frontend sub-directory:

`'/home/trones/Documents/git_repos/practice-and-examples/Angular/rxjs/convert to real api calls/frontend/tsconfig.json'`

My current workaround is to simply open two instances of vscode (one for frontend, one for backend).

Note: Linting is only for the frontend directory, I don't want it in the backend... this entire project is just to test something out, but I expect this to be a common scenario (wanting only a specific directory to be linted while having vs-code opened to a parent directory)... not sure why I've never had problems before.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by modifying .eslintrc.json's
overrides.parserOptions.project value

.eslintrc.json

```
{
...
 "overrides": [
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "./frontend/tsconfig.json"
        ]}]
...
}
```